# How to get rid of the spaces between CSS nav element borders?

Tags: css, menu, navigation

I have a CSS horizontal nav bar and I am using border-left and border-right to create the two-toned dividers between each menu item. For some reason, though, there is a space between the borders and I don't know how to get rid of it.

Here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/ebZhW/1/

Here is my CSS:

```
* {
    margin:0 ;
    padding:0 ;
}

body {
    background:#ffffff ;
    padding:40px 0 ;
    font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif ;
    color:#131313 ;
}


#topnav {
    width:100% ;
    height:36px ;
    -webkit-border-radius:8px 8px 0 0 ;
    -moz-border-radius:8px 8px 0 0 ;
    border-radius:8px 8px 0 0 ;
    background: #A50000;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 bottom, from(#A50000), to(#a10000));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#A50000, #a10000);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#A50000, #a10000);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(#A50000, #a10000);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#A50000, #a10000);
    background: linear-gradient(#A50000, #a10000);
    -pie-background: linear-gradient(#A50000, #a10000);
    behavior: url(/pie/PIE.htc);
    position:relative ;
    top:87px ;
    z-index:50 ;
    }

    ul.menu {
    margin-left:0 ;
    padding-left:0 ;
    list-style-type:none ;
    }

    .menu li {
    display:inline ;
    color:#ffffff ;
    border-left:1px solid #5d0000 ;
    border-right: 1px solid #d31a1a ;
    padding:0 16px ;
    margin:0 !important ;
    }

    .menu li a {
    font-size:16px ;
    color:#ffffff ;
    text-decoration:none ;
    line-height:36px ;
    }

    .menu li:first-child {
    border-left:0px !important ;
    }

    .menu li:last-child {
    border-right:0px !important ;
}
```

and my menu code:

```
    <div id="topnav">
    <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Events</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">News / Press</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Photo Gallery</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The spaces appear because you set each `li` to display `inline`. This causes whitespace between the tags to render (From your carriage returns).

Remove the whitespace like so:

```
    <div id="topnav">
    <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li><li><a href="#">Events</a></li><li><a href="#">News / Press</a></li><li><a href="#">Photo Gallery</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ebZhW/2/

Alternatively you can `float` the list-items to have them appear on the same line without forcing them to be treated as an inline element:

http://jsfiddle.net/ebZhW/3/

Comment: You can alternatively try to display `<li>` as block-level elements, and float them :)

Comment: @teddyrised snap - was writing that as you commented... great minds :)

Comment: Darn, you edited your answer to include one of the suggestions I had that made my answer different...

Comment: @GeorgeReith High five. I used to use the negative margin hack for inline listed items, and realize that they're not too helpful when you have flexible font sizes (unless you use ems, but it's generally clunky)

Answer (score 0):

The white-space between the elements is being rendered because of the way you are `display:`ing the elements.  There are several solutions including removing the white-space from the DOM.  You can also add these rules:

```
.menu {
    font-size: 0;
}
.menu li {
    font-size: /* whatever this is supposed to be */;
}
```

...which will prevent any white-space from showing up inside of the `<ul>`

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/ebZhW/4/

You could instead add `float: left` to the `li` elements.  This will make them float with respect to the white-space, so it will not appear.  It also makes the border extend the entire way vertically, which may be more desirable.

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/ebZhW/5/